# Has anyone added breadcrumbs to gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think I saw it listed as a feature for next version of ignition, but I am looking to add breadcrumbs to gazebo-11. Has anyone ever done this? Any ideas on how it would be possible?

By breadcrumb, I just mean a line that follows robot and shows its past path.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24843/has-anyone-added-breadcrumbs-to-gazebo?/) by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-16**:
You could clarify what aspect of breadcrumbs you're talking about. Is it just models that can be dropped from another, or also the communication aspect and so on.

**Comment by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on 2020-04-16**:
I mean just a line that follows the robot to see where it has moved during a simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> just a line that follows the robot to see where it has moved during a simulation.

Oh for that, try [LinkPlot3DPlugin](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1LinkPlot3DPlugin.html#details).

---

Just for future reference, this is different from what we've been referring to as "breadcrumbs" on Ignition. In that case, breadcrumbs are physical models that can be spawned and dropped behind; they can be moved, picked up and so on.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on 2020-04-17**:
Close, but I need the line to be displayed in 3d viewer. Not just a plot.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-17**:
Yeah that's on 3D, as the name says  Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egWAMbU7f6Y

**Comment by [LakeWorthB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24412/lakeworthb/) on 2020-04-17**:
Great thanks.